# 2-line bash prompt - why can the user backspace entire second line including prompt characters

Tags: bash

I have a bash prompt as follows:

```
$ echo $PS1
\[\033[1;31m\]\t \[\033[1;32m\]\u@\[\033[0;32m\]\[\033[4;32m\]\h\[\033[m \[\033[1;36m\]\w \[\033[0;33m\][\!] \[\033[0;36m\]{e=$?}\n\[\033[m\$ 
01:51:41 dinesh@c1 ~/lab [1030] {e=0}
$
```

But if I were to type something and then backspace, I can backspace all the way to the start of line, erasing even the "$ ". Why is that, how can it be made to stop backspacing at "$ "?

However if I changed it to:

```
PS1="LINE1\nLINE 2> "
```

then the backspacing stops at where prompt ends.

GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enclose all the non-printing ANSI escape sequences in `\[...\]`. You're missing a `\]` for the last one.

Comment: This saves my day! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the final `\]` before the last `m`. You need `\[` and `\]` around all non-printing characters, but not around the printing ones. Since you're missing the closing `\]`, the dollar sign is not calculated as a printing character.

Answer (score 0):

Move around your last `\n` to be right before `\$` will fix the problem:

Your original one (leading part omitted)

```
....\n\[\033[m\$
```

Changed to this  (leading part omitted):

```
....\[\033[m\n\$
```